# Как протестировать запуск jnlp из ant?

Tags: ant, javaws, java

Есть удаленное javaws-приложение (jnlp-файл), известен его url. Периодически этот jnlp-файл теряет работоспособность: при запуске падает исключение. Появилась идея написать тест, который проверяет возможность запуска javaws-приложения. Но при этом ведет себя "тихо". То есть само приложение не открывается, логотип Java с прогрессом загрузке не появляется, и т.д. Простой ant-тест, который либо падает с сообщением в консоли, либо успешно проходит без всяких сообщений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) выполняет системные команды (в данном случае команду javaws). failonerror - при возникновении ошибки тест считается не пройденным. Ключ import говорит о том, что мы не запускаем наш jnlp, а только создаем/обновляем локальный кэш. Ключ silent, - используется только в связке с import, - выполняет команду javaws без пользовательского интерфейса, а состояние показывает только с помощью кода возврата (0 - всё хорошо).

```
<exec executable="javaws" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="-silent" />
  <arg value="-import" />
  <arg value="${jnlp.url}" />
</exec>
```